# Broadleaf Commerece Tomcat installation

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, broadleaf-commerce

I have successfully installed Broadleaf Demo site with the help of ecllipse,Now i want to install it in tomcat standalone,so any body cant tell me the steps or any link will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bulid the war file of the project using eclipse .
then deploy that war file in that tomcat webapps folder.
now start the tomcat service.

Comment: I tried to run the admin.war file using standalone tomcat, but i am having error in server starting.


[ WARN] 17:46:12 RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer - Unable to determine runtime environment, using default environment 'development'
[ WARN] 17:46:20 MergePersistenceUnitManager - A BroadleafClassTransformer is configured for this persistence unit, but Spring reported a pr
y.DirectCopyClassTransformer) is not being registered with the persistence unit.

Comment: Navigate to the `site` subproject. Open `development.properties` in side the src->main->resources->runtime-properties. Add/ Change `blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do followings;

(a)In the site and admin directory of the pom.xml fileAdding region:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>${webappDirectory}</warSourceDirectory>
        <path>/</path>
        <port>${httpPort}</port>
        <httpsPort>${httpsPort}</httpsPort>
        <keystoreFile>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/blc-example.keystore</keystoreFile>
        <keystorePass>broadleaf</keystorePass>
        <password>broadleaf</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

(b)Right click DemoSite project in eclipse, Go to `run` -> `Run As` and execute the `Maven clean` and `Maven install`, After successful execution WAR files will be generated in the corresponding target folders inside the Demosite `admin` and `site` folders accordingly. We generated two war package named admin.war and mycompany.war.

(c)If Your environment is Ubuntu, the path to the webapps Tomcat server for `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`, admin and mycompany.war will be copied to the folder, and then restart the Tomcat server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart
```

See the /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out file error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readMethods(ClassParser.java:268)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2105)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1981)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1947)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1932)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1326)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1673)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        ... 4 more
```

For the memory overflow problem, the following specific solutions: 
Catalina.sh files in Ubuntu (path for the file is /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh), add the following content in the first line in the document:

```
JAVA_OPTS='-server -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M' #Note: single quotation marks can not be omitted
```

Catalina.bat files in windows, in the first row, add the following content:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M #Note: no single quotation marks
```

(d)According to (c) in the modified after the restart the Tomcat server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart
```

You can normal open electric page in the browser: localhost:8080/mycompany and background management page: localhost:8080/admin, to transfer Tomcat server also be accomplished.